# Compare Combobox to a row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, compare

I have a combo box and a datagridview. I am importing an excel file into the datragridview and in one of the rows in the datagridview, in the third row, it should be a string that is one of the options for the selections in the combo box which was previously mentioned.

This is my current thought process right now .. I think I am on the right path?

Can't figure out if there is a string.compare procedure like in C++

```
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In datagridview.Rows
            If (Datagridview1.Rows(2).cells(0).Value.ToString().Contains(Combobox.Text) Then
                Msgbox("they are the same value")
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has it a bit backwards

```
If cboName.Items.Contains(Datagridview1.Rows(2).cells(0).Value.ToString()) Then
```

cboName is the Name of your ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this too:

```
For y=0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 'Loops trough rows
        If Combobox1.Items.Contains(DataGridView1(0,y).Value.ToString()) Then 'Checks if combobox has something named the same way as cell
            Msgbox("they are the same value")
        End If
Next
```